# Convert a datetime to string

Tags: c#

Howsit!

I encounter an error when i get a null value in my datareader.

```
public List<Complaint> View_all_complaints()
{
    csDAL objdal= new csDAL();
    List<Complaint> oblcomplist=new List<Complaint>();

    using( IDataReader dr=objdal.executespreturndr("View_all_complaints"))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Complaint objcomp= new Complaint();
            populate_reader(dr,objcomp);
            oblcomplist.Add(objcomp);
        }
    }
    return oblcomplist;
}

public void populate_reader(IDataReader dr, Complaint objcomp)
{
    objcomp.ref_num = dr.GetString(0);
    objcomp.type = dr.GetString(1);
    objcomp.desc = dr.GetString(2);
    objcomp.date = dr.GetDateTime(3);
    objcomp.housenum = dr.GetInt32(4);
    objcomp.streetnum = dr.GetInt32(5);
    objcomp.status = dr.GetString(6);
    objcomp.priority = dr.GetString(7);
    objcomp.cid = dr.GetInt32(8);
    if (!dr.IsDBNull(9))
    {
        objcomp.resolved_date = dr.GetDateTime(9);
    }
}
```

in sql resolved date allows null values, this is so because only when a complaint has been resolved , it must reflect that date otherwise it should be null.

if dr.getdatetime(9) is null then it must just set a string saying "Not Resolved"

please help!

Comment: Are you sure the null in the 9th column? What exact line throw the error?

Comment: I tried this: objcomp.resolved_date.ToString() = Convert.ToString(dr.GetDateTime(9)); it gives me this error:Error 11 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Comment: thanx it was actually 10 but now i get "data type is null, cannot be a null value!

Comment: @Kuven Ramsamy, you can't use assignment  in function you can use `==` in thihs case tocheck whether equal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown what your `Complaint` type looks like, but basically you'll want to make sure that its `resolved_date` is of type `DateTime?` aka `Nullable<DateTime>`. That allows you to *model* a missing value elegantly.

As for *displaying* it - you haven't shown anything about where you display the data, but you'd want something like:

```
string text = complaint.ResolvedDate.HasValue ? complaint.ResolvedDate.ToString()
                                              : "Not Resolved";
```

(I've changed this to use a property with the idiomatic name at the same time...)

Comment: objcomp.resolved_date = **dr.GetDateTime(10);**

            string text = objcomp.resolved_date.HasValue ? objcomp.resolved_date.ToString() : "Not Resolved";
            
            
                
        }

the error still comes up by [**dr.GetDateTime(10)**] Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy: So don't call it in that case - you've already got `if (!dr.IsDBNull(9))` - that should sort it.

Comment: it now runs, but when displayed in a grid in an the presentation layer, how do the variable text? in the resolved date column it displays the date as 0001/01/01 12:00PM... its ok i guess since there is no such year as the above, but it would look more presentable if it said "Not Available" im still a student n still learnin

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy: Well you need to include the logic I presented in my answer somewhere in your code - but you haven't told us anything about presentation layer.

Comment: Thanx Jon!I used this under the datagrid  itemdatabound event:protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Item.Cells)
            {
                 

                if (e.Item.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell) == 12 && e.Item.DataSetIndex >= 0)
                {
                     

                    if (Convert.ToString(cell.Text) == "0001/01/01 12:00:00 AM")
                    {
                        cell.Text = "Not Resolved";
                    }

                    
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

IDataReader has a "[IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull.aspx)" method, that should be called before calling GetXXX(), in case your value is not nullable.

For example:

```
objcomp.date = dr.GetDateTime(3);
```

should be:

```
objcomp.date = dr.IsDBNull(3) ? DateTime.MinValue : dr.GetDateTime(3);
```

Comment: It's much cleaner to change the property/field to be a nullable type than to use DateTime.MinValue as a "magic" value, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree (how can I argue with JonSkeet?!), but that would require changing the Model, which might not always be feasible. Also, sometimes having a "default" value makes perfect sense...